# Deploying Django on EC2

Tags: django, deployment, amazon-ec2

I'm having a django project that should be deployed on Amazon's EC2. There are various tutorials on installing django on EC2, but I think it'll always be a time consuming step to generate a new AMI image with your whole application... So I was thinking that it should also be possible to deploy it on the persistent storage, EBS? 
But I'm wondering if that would have any disadvantages because there are no tutorials describing that out there... So if anybody is having some ideas on that or having any other tutorials on how to deploy new versions in an easy fast way to EC2 please let me know!

Comment: Any specific reason on trying to deploy on ec2 rather than using something like Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 3):

I used Bitnami Djangostack 1.2.3 (I'm not associated with bitnami in any way).
http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack

The EC2 image is "ami-18fb0f71", described as "bitnami-djangostack-1.2.3-0-linux-ubuntu-10.04-ebs".

This is an EBS backed instance, but I can't comment on advantages/disadvantages of this.

I found some of the pertinent configuration files in these locations:
/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
/opt/bitnami/apps/django/conf/django.conf

The file served by default (as configured in httpd.conf) is '/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/index.html'.

You can get a bit of support here:
http://bitnami.org/forums/forums/djangostack

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be fine. At the least, you can experiment: get an EBS-backed instance, install django, stop the instance (not terminate!) and snapshot the volume (for backup).

Restart the instance, and see.